# Retrieve XML of large plan from plan cache

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan

I'm trying to view (graphically) a large query plan that is in the plan cache and am running into problems where the XML is truncated in the query results.  This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    size_in_bytes,
    query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY size_in_bytes DESC
```

I've tried it in SSMS and when I click on the XML in the results grid I get the `Unable to show XML. Unexpected end of file when parsing Name has occurred.  Line 1, position 2097154.` If I copy and paste the XML it is indeed truncated.

I've tried manually using `SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647` just because, and that didn't do anything.  (I know that's the default value for the SQL Native Client providers, was just trying to force the issue).

I've tried running the statement via `SQLCMD` from a .sql file and outputting to a text file but that gives me even less.

I've tried using `SQLCMD` interactively, with `:XML ON` and got this error:

```
<?MSSQLError HResult="0x80004005" Source="Microsoft XML Extensions to SQL Server" Description="No description provided"?>
```

The plan is 157 MB.

Is there any way to get the full plan out so that I can see it?

Comment: Have you tried the `-y` argument to `sqlcmd`? Should let you choose the maximum size of returned fields.

Comment: @Simon No, I have not.  Thanks, I'll go try that in a minute.

Comment: @Simon No luck.  Max value for column length is 8000 and that's not enough.  XML is still truncated.

Comment: How about retrieving the data using C# or PowerShell.

Comment: @Aaron I can give that a try.  I'd expect to run into the same thing, though, as the providers would be the same.  Unless there's a different provider I could find that doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: What is `Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid -> Maximum Characters Retrieved -> XML data` set to? If not already unlimited does changing that work?

Comment: As an alternative, How abt save the results to a file and view from there?

Comment: @Martin Ah, that was it!  That was what I should have been changing instead of SET TEXTSIZE (under Query Execution -> SQL Server).  I'm getting the full XML now.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @Sankar I tried that also.  Same results as the grid.

Comment: I'm intrigued. For academic purposes, any chance of eyeballs on the 157MB execution plan? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For 157MB in `Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid` screen you will need to set `Maximum Characters Retrieved -> XML data` to unlimited as below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: An anonymous editor just suggested that restarting SSMS was neccesary after changing this setting. I don't believe this to be the case so rejected the edit but mention it here in case it was valid.

Comment: Restart of SSMS is not needed; You will have to open a new query window, tho.

Comment: @MartinSmith +1 - FYI I just had to restart SSMS to get this to work.

Comment: Restarting SSMS after the change mentioned above worked. Did not work without restarting SSMS.

Comment: Changing the XML Data setting in the SSMS Options did work for me when I encountered this issue, but not until after restarting SSMS. I am using SSMS 2012.

Comment: IIRC, you may have to create a new query window.  You shouldn't have to restart SSMS, though that should also work.